How to find best fitting trend that fits this periodic data?
I have this data only for this month and I need to find a good trend function. I used a polynomial of degree 6 but with that you can't really extrapolate. I heard you should use Fourier series? It is also not like sine or cosine function since the middle of the data is almost constant, the periodicity is only at the beginning or end of the month.enter image description here

The only sensible extrapolation from this data with no other context is to assume that every month looks just like this one. No formula can tell you more than that. If you want something smooth that polynomial is as good as anything else, although it is not smooth at the start and end of the month.

There are several issues to think about here. You have time as your $x$ axis, but you are missing weekends and Christmas (actually the day after, since Christmas was on a Sunday). If you use the date as the $x$ values, then you will get a different curve - interpolating for the missing days - than if you use column number as the $x$ values. If you are attempting to predict other months, then you will at least want to interpolate in Christmas. But it is hard to imagine an industry where applying December data to other months will give good results. Even those not affected by Christmas ...

''' will likely be affected by the end of the year.  Fourier series might give a shape you like better in this case. To find the coefficients, use an FFT, "Fast Fourier Transform" algorithm. Cooley-Tukey would be a good choice (you can find better explanations of how it works elsewhere than wikipedia, though).
